# How to read a binary file with TCL

Tags: input, file-io, output, tcl, binaryfiles

So I have a function I'm using to read data from a file. It works fine if the file is plain text, but when I try to read a binary file, like a png, it returns a different text (`diff` confirms that). I opened a hex editor to see what was wrong and found out it is putting some `c2` bytes along with the file (I don't know if the position is random or if there are other bytes except this `c2` one).

This is my function. I just want it to read and save to a variable.

```
proc read_file {path} {
        set channel [open $path r]
        fconfigure $channel -translation binary
        set return_string "[read $channel]"
        close $channel
        return "$return_string"
}
```

To actually print, I'm doing this:

```
puts -nonewline [read_file file.png]
```

Comment: You have to set the channel you're writing to as binary, too.

Comment: Oh, and you don't need any of those quotes.

Comment: @Shawn Solved. How do I close this question?

Answer (score 0):

When you open a file, it defaults to being in text mode . In text mode (which is really a combination of options) the IO layer translates characters from whatever encoding they are in into Tcl's internal encoding, and does the reverse operation on output. The default encoding scheme is platform specific, but in your case it sounds like it is UTF-8. (Tcl uses a complex internal system of encodings; it doesn't expose those to the outside world.)

By contrast, when you put the channel into binary mode, the bytes on the outside are directly mapped to characters in the range 0-255 (and *vice versa* on output). You get a perfect copy, provided you put *both* input and output channels in binary mode. (There are other optimisations for binary mode, but they don't matter here.)

When you only put one of the channels in binary mode, you get what looks like corruption. It isn't random though. In particular, when the input is binary but the output is UTF-8, input bytes in the range 128-255 get converted into multiple output bytes, where the first of those bytes is in the sort of range you observed. There are other combinations that mess things up; the whole range of problems is collectively known as mojibake.

**tl;dr** Don't mix up binary and text data unless you're very careful. The results of getting it wrong are "surprising".